# MOSEK C api time limit

Tags: performance, optimization, mosek

I'm trying to find a way to limit the time of execution of `MSK_optimize` routine. However, browsing through MOSEK docs gives me nothing. I have tried with:

```
MSK_putnaintparam( task, "MSK_DPAR_OPTIMIZER_MAX_TIME", 1 );
```

and playing with the value on the right, but this does not seem to solve the problem and looks like it does not even affect MOSEK. Setting `MSK_DPAR_MIO_MAX_TIME` manually is not possible. Other than that, I have found nothing that can influence maximum time MOSEK will run. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function MSK_putnaintparam( task, "MSK_DPAR_OPTIMIZER_MAX_TIME", 1 );  would have returned a proper error code. So if you did not ignore those you would have discovered your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that could find this helpful:

The problem is that `MSK_DPAR_OPTIMIZER_MAX_TIME` is a double and not an integer parameter. After losing a whole day on this, I finally found that putting:

```
MSK_putnadouparam( task, "MSK_DPAR_OPTIMIZER_MAX_TIME", 1 );
```

does the trick.